# Skip positions on ties in RANK function

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to skip positions on ties

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
Name varchar(50),
totalrate int,
nrrates int
);


INSERT INTO Persons (Name, totalrate, nrrates) VALUES
         ('Albert', 80, 8),
         ('Ben', 65, 7),
         ('Brittany', 65, 7),
         ('Carl', 64, 7),
         ('Danna', 62, 7);

SELECT   `Name`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`),
         @rank_count := @rank_count + (totalrate/nrrates < @prev_value) rank,
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     Persons, (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1) init
ORDER BY avg DESC
```

I get

```
Name    (`totalrate` / `nrrates`)   rank    avg 
Albert                10             1     10
Ben               9.2857             2   9.285714285
Brittany          9.2857             2   9.285714285
Carl              9.1429             3   9.142857142
Danna             8.8571             4   8.857142857
```

I Want to skip the third position and have the fourth place not ranked third

```
Name    (`totalrate` / `nrrates`)   rank    avg 
Albert          10                    1      10
Ben         9.2857                    2     9.285714285
Brittany    9.2857                    2     9.285714285
Carl        9.1429                    4     9.142857142
Danna       8.8571                    5     8.857142857
```

I hope there is enough information to create the table and run the function on sql It ruins in my xammp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce another variable:

```
SELECT   `Name`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) as avg,
         (@rank_count := if((@rn := (@rn + 1)) > 0,
                            if((totalrate/nrrates < @prev_value),
                               @rn,
                               @rank_count), NULL)
         ) as rank,
         @prev_value := totalrate/nrrates avg
FROM     Persons CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT @prev_value := NULL, @rank_count := 1, @rn := 0) init
ORDER BY avg DESC;
```

Note that I put the assignment of `@rn` into the same expression as `@rank_count`.  MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`.  If they are done in the wrong order then the code will not do what you expect.

I didn't change the `@prev_value` because it is currently working and rewriting that code would change what the query looks like -- hiding the simple change of just adding the `@rn`.

Comment: you forgot a comma, but thanks it works! i will implement it to my bigger script to see if it runs also

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
     , FIND_IN_SET(totalrate,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(totalrate ORDER BY totalrate DESC) FROM persons )) rank
  FROM persons;
```